# How can I implement BeanPostProcessor with nullable "beanName" in Kotlin?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

The problem is that I need to make `beanName` nullable. Because of some parts of spring pass `null` instead of valid bean name( Quartz for example). The same implementation on Java works properly.

I've tried to add JetBrain's `@Nullable` annotation. It doesn't work. And the decompiled class seems [strange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y14Qr.png). Moreover, I've made a full clone of `BeanPostProcessor` in project folder with a different name, made implementation on kotlin and made `beanName` nullable without any errors.

```
//Java
package org.myapp;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;

// My clone of BeanPostProcessor
public interface CloneOfBeanPostProcessor {

    @Nullable
        default Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean;
        }

    @Nullable
    default Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}

// Kotlin
package org.myapp

import org.myapp.CloneOfBeanPostProcessor
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component


@Component
class MessageSourceBeanPostProcessorOld : CloneOfBeanPostProcessor {
    // Have no warnings in this case.
    override fun postProcessAfterInitialization(bean: Any, beanName: String?): Any? {...}
```

Kotlin problem example below. Here I get a `'postProcessAfterInitialization' overrides nothing` if I add `?` to beanName type:

```
@Component
class MessageSourceBeanPostProcessorOld : BeanPostProcessor {
    override fun postProcessAfterInitialization(bean: Any, beanName: String?): Any? {...}
```

Same code on Java works well:

```
@Component
class MessageSourceBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {...}
```

Now we use spring-boot version 2.0.6. In 2.1.x version problem doesn't reproduce. However, I want to get clear with this problem. Is it a gap in my knowledge or it's a bug, and I should report it?

UPD:
As Eugene said, the problem was in the non-null API declaration at the package level introduced in the spring 5.x. Problem solved by upgrade spring-boot version to 2.1.x(at least for quartz autoconfiguration problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring uses a package-wide annotation to declare that all parameters (unless specified explicitly) are non-nullable.

You may add a tiny Java abstract class in the middle and clearly mark all parameters with `@Nullable` annotation. Inheriting from that type should work for your case